# Default value for React state storing integer values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `selectedId` React state that stores integer values. The state is updated with an `id` integer, when an item is selected from a list. Once `selectedId` is set, the user can click a `delete` button to delete the selected element, after which `selectedId` should be set back to its initial value again.

What is the recommended default value for `selectedId`? Should it set to null ( `useState(null)` and `setSelectedId(null)` ), or be undefined ( `setSelectedId()` )

```js
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();
```

```js
const handleSelect = id => {
  setIsAlertOpen(true);
  setSelectedId(id);
};
```

```js
<Button onClick={() => {
  deleteItem(selectedId)
  setSelectedId();
}/>
```

Comment: add `null` as a initial value, that is recommended.

Comment: I add zero if it does not be in the id list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a constant to store the initial value, and when you delete the `selectedId` restore it your initial value.

```
const initialValue = null;
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(initialValue);

const handleSelect = id => {
  setIsAlertOpen(true);
  setSelectedId(id);
};

<Button onClick={() => {
  deleteItem(selectedId)
  setSelectedId(initialValue);
}/>
```